# Segmentation Fault with Gensim

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, gensim

I am currently getting a segmentation fault when I am loading a model with gensim. In order to create the model and save it, I do:

```
glove_file = 'QGModels/embeddings/glove.6B.300d.txt'
tmp_file = 'QGModels/embeddings/word2vec-glove.6B.300d.txt'
glove2word2vec(glove_file, tmp_file)
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(tmp_file)
model.save('QGModels/embeddings/model.model')
```

However the problem starts when I load the model and use the most_similar method using:

```
model = KeyedVectors.load('QGModels/embeddings/model.model')
closestWords = model.most_similar(positive=[answer], topn=count)
```

And then get a segmentation fault:

> Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

Any and all help is appreciated! Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had too many Firefox tabs open. Closing most of them helped fix the Segmentation Fault.

Comment: As a `SIGKILL`, rather than another kind of access-error, it may have been your OS picking a process to kill upon reaching a low-memory condition. If you keep having memory-issues, note that such word-vector sets are *usually* sorted to put the most frequent/important words 1st, and the `load_word2vec_format()` method has an optional `limit` parameter to only read a subset of the words - so you could easily drop the rarest words to save memory.

Comment: @gojomo thank you for the insight! I'll keep that in mind for the future!